# Replicate PHP ImageMagick's paintOpaqueImage Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, imagemagick

ImageMagick has a function that allows you to scan through a picture and replace all the colors that are roughly a color you specify and replace these colors with another color you specify.

I'm interested in replicating this functionality using JavaScript. That is, I would like apply an image filter that changes every color that is approximately red to black, for instance. How would this be possible?

Side note: I tested out a GitHub project that somehow manages to clone ImageMagick's functionality using web workers. Sadly, it is too slow (takes 5.632 seconds to load an image with the filter I want from a local server.. and I'm trying to apply the filter twice). It's pretty cool though - https://github.com/manuels/unix-toolbox.js-imagemagick.

Comment: You can read each pixel's RGB values with [CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and write with [CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData). I've once used them for a sort of image morphing demo, but the speed was very disappointing. Maybe, WebGL can be an answer. I found an inspiring project called [WebGL Filter](http://evanw.github.io/webgl-filter/) though it doesn't cover what you are looking for, exactly.

Comment: thanks.. should be fun to look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick and dirty WebGL [code](http://jsfiddle.net/ryubro/0f3oaqae/1/) mostly copied from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Getting_started_with_WebGL and http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html.

Changing color happens in the vertex shader which is from line 14 in the html file.

```
<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;

    uniform sampler2D uSampler;

    uniform highp vec4 uOrigColor;
    uniform highp vec4 uDestColor;

    void main(void) {
        highp vec4 orig = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
        highp vec4 dest = orig;
        highp float gap = 0.05; // threshold
        if (orig.r > uOrigColor.r - gap && orig.r < uOrigColor.r + gap
            && orig.g > uOrigColor.g - gap && orig.g < uOrigColor.g + gap 
            && orig.b > uOrigColor.b - gap && orig.b < uOrigColor.b + gap) {
            dest = uDestColor;
        }
        gl_FragColor = dest;
    }
</script>
```

To test: http://jsfiddle.net/ryubro/0f3oaqae/1/

Comment: This is beast... how can I thank you? What's your bitcoin address or whatever?

Comment: Thank you! I was self motivated because I learned openGL just a few weeks ago. Your up vote, acceptation and appreciation are enough for me. : )

Comment: so how do I use this after I've copied the script from above? say I have an image with id="thisimage" and I want to change #000000 to #FFFFFF

Comment: @user2476265 Change the ```rainbowImage.src``` on line 201 of the javascript file. I used base64 data encoding because of the cross-domain issue. You'll be fine if the image you want to use is served in the same domain as your javascript is served.

To change color, fill the from & to input fields and click the change button.

Comment: thanks.. I understand that but I'm wondering how I can include this as a function where I automatically change all images with a certain class with #000000 in them to #FFFFFF... any idea on how I can accomplish this?